# Attached pdf in rails app error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, actionmailer

Im implementing and mvc rails app, ***i can attach a pdf to an email and send it***.
But when im traying to open the attached file from my gmail the browser shows:

> Failed to load PDF document

Controller:

```
def update
 if !params[:attachment].nil? && !params[:attachment].blank?
   @file = Tempfile.new([params[:attachment], '.pdf']) 
   s = StringIO.new(params[:attachment])
   def s.original_filename; "Answer.pdf"; end
   @file_name = s.original_filename
 else
    @file = ""
    @file_name = ""
 end 
 respond_to do |format|
      if @study_request.update(study_request_params)
        format.html { redirect_to study_requests_path, notice: 'Answer Sended.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @study_request }
        enviar()
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @study_request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
 end
end
def enviar()
            mail = StudyRequestMailer.new_analysis(@study_request,@file_name,@file)
            mail.deliver_now
end
```

View:

```
<div class="ui form">
  <%= form_with(model: study_request, local: true) do |form| %>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
   <div class="field">
     <%= file_field_tag :attachment,:class=>"form-control btn-metis-7 btn-file" %>
     <%= form.submit "Send Mail", :class => 'ui fluid large teal submit button' %>
   </div>
  <%end%>
</div>
```

Mailer:

```
class StudyRequestMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def new_analysis(studyRequest,file_name,file)
    @studyRequest = studyRequest
    if file != ""
      attachments[file_name] = File.read(file)
    end
    mail to: @studyRequest.email, subject: "Answer"
  end
end
```

Comment: replace this line `attachments[file_name] = File.read(file)` with  `attachments["file_name.pdf"] =  File.read(file)`

Comment: Let me know if it is working or not